How to Optimize Parking Slot Simulation to Handle More Cars Without Duplication
I have a parking slot simulation program to test my parking counter code, but it's currently limited to simulating only 4 cars. The main issue is the redundancy in the floor_wait functions, which only handle one floor each. I want to scale the simulation to handle more cars efficiently without duplicating the code for each floor.
# Import library
import json
import threading
import queue
import time
import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#try catch block

# need to make more queues if you want more floors (the Wq one)
iq = queue.Queue()
wq1 = queue.Queue()
wq2 = queue.Queue()
wq3 = queue.Queue()
oq = queue.Queue()
lock = threading.Lock()
TEMP_FILE = 'parking_slot.json'  # File path

# Load or initialize parking state 
try:
    with open(TEMP_FILE, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        total_slots = data.get('total_slots', 300)
        floor_slots = data.get('floor_slots', {'Floor 1': 100, 'Floor 2': 100, 'Floor 3': 100})
except FileNotFoundError:
    total_slots = 300
    floor_slots = {'Floor 1': 100, 'Floor 2': 100, 'Floor 3': 100}

# For the windows display stuff
root = Tk()
frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
total_label = ttk.Label(frm, text=f"Total slots: {total_slots}")
floor_labels = {}

# code not used juut here if i want to update it with a saving feature
def save_data():
    data = {
        'total_slots': total_slots,
        'floor_slots': floor_slots
    }
    with open(TEMP_FILE, 'w') as temp_file:
        json.dump(data, temp_file)

def stop_threads():
    iq.put(None)  # Signal to floor_input to stop
    wq1.put(None)  # Signal to floor1_wait to stop
    wq2.put(None)  # Signal to floor2_wait to stop
    wq3.put(None)  # Signal to floor3_wait to stop
    oq.put(None)  # Signal to main_output to stop

def window_display():  # code to display the slots
    global total_slots, floor_slots, floor_labels, root, total_label, frm
    root.title("Car Park Display Counter Simulation")
    frm.grid()
    total_label.grid(column=0, row=0)
    for i, (floor, slots) in enumerate(floor_slots.items()):
        floor_label = ttk.Label(frm, text=f"{floor}: {slots} slots")
        floor_label.grid(column=0, row=i + 1)
        floor_labels[floor] = floor_label

    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", stop_threads)

def update_data():  # Code to update the window that displays the slots
    global total_slots, floor_slots, floor_labels, root, total_label
    root.after(0, lambda: total_label.config(text=f"Total slots: {total_slots}"))
    for floor in floor_slots.keys():
        root.after(0, lambda floor=floor: floor_labels[floor].config(text=f"{floor}: {floor_slots[floor]} slots"))

def main_input():
    global total_slots 
    for i in range(100):  # Chhange this depending on how many cars u want to go in
        if total_slots > 0:
            car = f'car {random.randint(1, 100)}'  # Generate a unique car name
            iq.put(car)
            total_slots -= 1
            update_data()
        else:
            time.sleep(1)  # Wait a bit if no slots are available

        time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 3))  # Simulates human delay

        if not iq.empty() and iq.queue[0] is None:
            break

def floor_input():  # Code that decides on what floor the car will go to
    global floor_slots
    while True:
        try:
            car = iq.get(timeout=1)
        except queue.Empty:
            continue
        
        if car is None:
            break
        floor_name = random.choice(list(floor_slots.keys()))
        with lock:  # A lock to prevent race conditions
            if floor_slots[floor_name] > 0:  # Check if there are available slots on the floor
                floor_slots[floor_name] -= 1 
                wait_time = {
                    'Floor 1': 1,
                    'Floor 2': 2,
                    'Floor 3': 3,
                }.get(floor_name, 1)
                time.sleep(wait_time)
                
                # Direct the car to the appropriate queue based on the floor
                if floor_name == 'Floor 1':
                    wq1.put(car)
                elif floor_name == 'Floor 2':
                    wq2.put(car)
                elif floor_name == 'Floor 3':
                    wq3.put(car)
            else:
                iq.put(car)  # If no slots are available, put the car back in the input queue

            if not iq.empty() and iq.queue[0] is None:
                break

        update_data()

def floor1_wait():  # The code that simulates the car waiting in the parking space
    global floor_slots
    while True:
        try:
            car1 = wq1.get(timeout=1)
        except queue.Empty:
            continue  
        if car1 is None:
            break
        time.sleep(random.uniform(3, 8))  # Car waiting simulation
        floor_slots['Floor 1'] += 1
        oq.put(car1)
        update_data()
        time.sleep(1)  # Car going to the exit
        if not wq1.empty() and wq1.queue[0] is None:
            break

def floor2_wait():  # The code that simulates the car waiting in the parking space
    global floor_slots
    while True:
        try:
            car2 = wq2.get(timeout=1)
        except queue.Empty:
            continue  
        if car2 is None:
            break
        time.sleep(random.uniform(3, 8)) 
        floor_slots['Floor 2'] += 1
        oq.put(car2)
        update_data()
        time.sleep(2)
        if not wq2.empty() and wq2.queue[0] is None:
            break

def floor3_wait():  # The code that simulates the car waiting in the parking space
    global floor_slots
    while True:
        try:
            car3 = wq3.get(timeout=1)
        except queue.Empty:
            continue  
        if car3 is None:
            break
        time.sleep(random.uniform(3, 8))
        floor_slots['Floor 3'] += 1
        oq.put(car3)
        update_data()
        time.sleep(3)
        if not wq3.empty() and wq3.queue[0] is None:
            break

def main_output():  # Code that sorts out cars that are going out
    global total_slots  
    while True:
        try:
            car = oq.get(timeout=1)
        except queue.Empty:
            continue

        if car is None:
            break
        total_slots += 1
        update_data()
        time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 5))

    while not iq.empty():
        car = iq.get()
        if car is not None:
            total_slots += 1
            update_data()
            time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 5))

# Display the window
window_display()
update_data()

# Create threads
main_input_thread = threading.Thread(target=main_input)
floor_input_thread = threading.Thread(target=floor_input)
floor1_output_thread = threading.Thread(target=floor1_wait)
floor2_output_thread = threading.Thread(target=floor2_wait)
floor3_output_thread = threading.Thread(target=floor3_wait)
main_output_thread = threading.Thread(target=main_output)

# Start threads
main_input_thread.start()
floor_input_thread.start()
floor1_output_thread.start()
floor2_output_thread.start()
floor3_output_thread.start()
main_output_thread.start()

# Run the Tkinter main loop
root.mainloop()  # For the display window 

# After the GUI is closed, wait for threads to finish
main_input_thread.join()
floor_input_thread.join()
floor1_output_thread.join()
floor2_output_thread.join()
floor3_output_thread.join()
main_output_thread.join()

print("Simulation Ended.")               

The code works fine for now, but to simulate more than 4 cars, I need to avoid duplicating the floor_wait function for each floor. How can I refactor my code to handle more cars and floors efficiently?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

When you are tempted to use a global variable inside a method, you might consider if that variable should actually be passed as a parameter rather than used as a global.

When you are tempted to reference a global variable in a method, that might be a good indication that you might be able to pass that variable to the method as a parameter rather than reference it as a global.
Additionally, if you have several methods that do the same thing but differ only by variables with names like my_variable_1 and my_variable_2 that is a very strong flag that these methods should be combined and passed the appropriate value as a parameter.
Here is one example that preserves the rest of your code, but your code is full of such refactoring opportunities.
Rather than use many methods like:
def floor1_wait():  # The code that simulates the car waiting in the parking space
    global floor_slots
    while True:
        try:
            car1 = wq1.get(timeout=1)
        except queue.Empty:
            continue  
        if car1 is None:
            break
        time.sleep(random.uniform(3, 8))  # Car waiting simulation
        floor_slots['Floor 1'] += 1
        oq.put(car1)
        update_data()
        time.sleep(1)  # Car going to the exit
        if not wq1.empty() and wq1.queue[0] is None:
            break

You might try:
def floor_wait(wq, floor_slot, oq):
    while True:
        try:
            car = wq.get(timeout=1)
        except queue.Empty:
            break

        if not car:
            break

        time.sleep(random.uniform(3, 8))  # Car waiting simulation
        floor_slot += 1
        oq.put(car)
        update_data()
        time.sleep(1)  # Car going to the exit

Then you could replace:
floor1_output_thread = threading.Thread(target=floor1_wait)
floor2_output_thread = threading.Thread(target=floor2_wait)
floor3_output_thread = threading.Thread(target=floor3_wait)

with
floor1_output_thread = threading.Thread(target=floor_wait, args=(wq1, floor_slots['Floor 1'], oq))
floor2_output_thread = threading.Thread(target=floor_wait, args=(wq2, floor_slots['Floor 2'], oq))
floor3_output_thread = threading.Thread(target=floor_wait, args=(wq3, floor_slots['Floor 3'], oq))



Thankyou for your help! im going to try using this in my code and i'll give you an update
